# Switch case failing, returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bmi calculator and converted the conditionals to a switch statement to make it a bit cleaner. However, now the code is breaking and not causing the var result to be set so it can be displayed.

Any ideas what I am missing here?

JS

```
 $('#calculatebutton').click(function () {
         var weight = parseInt($('#weight-lb').val()),
             heightInches = parseInt($('#height-ft').val()) + parseInt($('#height-in').val()),
             heightsqaured = (heightInches) * (heightInches),
             result = ((weight) / (heightsqaured) * 703);


              switch(result) {

                case (result < 16):
                     var rating = 'You are severely underweight';
                     break;


                case (result > 16) && (result < 18.5):
                     var rating = 'You are underweight';
                     break;


                case (result > 18.5) && (result < 25):
                     var rating = 'You are healthy';
                     break;


                case (result > 25) && (result < 30):
                     var rating = 'You are overweight';
                     break;


                case (result > 30) && (result < 35):
                     var rating = 'You are moderately obese';
                     break;


                case (result > 80):
                     var rating = 'This result seems unlikely, please check that the information you have entered is correct';
                     break;       
            }

            $('#result').html('Your BMI is ' + result.toFixed(1) + '. ' + rating + '.');

     });
```

JS Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/o12xpy2s/

Comment: Something is getting calculated wrong... Check your ParseInts, you might need to ParseFloat or something like that. I get NaNs when JS can't calculate something. Do your Heights, have " or ' in them? like 5'4, for instance...

Comment: Have you checked the console? There's an extra `});`

Comment: Debugging is your friend. `console.log` your variables and see what their types are, and if theres something funky going on in the inputs

Comment: You are using switch wrong.  See the duplicate question. (`switch` is probably not a good fit here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
switch(result) {
```

...to:

```
switch(true) {
```

Your `switch` cases are all `true` or `false` conditions. So set your `switch` expression `switch(expression)` to one or the other. Here you're looking for the `true` condition of the listed `case`s.

Comment: @Miura-shi There also needs to be a 'default' case. Right now nothing is going to happen if the result is over 35 but under 80.

Comment: Yes. Or move the `var rating` before the `switch` and set the default there.